# Is it possible to determine how long a process has been running

Tags: c#, process

Is it possible, in C#, to get a list of running processes (not service processes, but actual applications) and get a DateTime of when the application started? Or a TimeSpan or even an integer of how long a process has been running?

Comment: ["c# get list of running processes"](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+get+list+of+running+processes), ["c# get process start time"](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+get+process+start+time)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`Process.GetProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) will retrieve a list of running processes.

Each [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) has a [`StartTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) property that

> Gets the time that the associated process was started.

Simply subtract that from [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) to get how long the process has been running.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var procs = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (var proc in procs) {
        TimeSpan runtime;
        try {
            runtime = DateTime.Now - proc.StartTime;
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex) {
            // Ignore processes that give "access denied" error.
            if (ex.NativeErrorCode == 5)
                continue;   
            throw;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", proc, runtime);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Didnt know that process has a start time property :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process.StartTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) and [Process.EndTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exittime.aspx).